# Bash script to pull from master every morning

Tags: bash, git, bash-scripting

I'm trying to automate my workplace as much as I can, but I'm kind of new to bash scripts. What is the best way to tell bash script to run `git co master` and if it is successful do `git pull` and once it is finished do some other commands? I need to do this every morning at 7am (can I schedule it directly in bash script?)

Answer (score 1):

You can string together commands using `&&` so:

```
#!/bin/bash
git co master && git pull && some_other_commands
```

To schedule, use cron if you are on Mac OS X or Unix/Linux.

The crontab entry would be:

```
* 7 * * * /path/to/your/bash/script
```

Comment: You could also check variable $? after running the command in an if statement to determine if it run successfully.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to use `git stash` to preserve changes to the local repo that haven't been checked in yet.